# How to use WARRANT as a verb?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1 It warrants my taking the measures.
>
> 2 It warrants me taking the measures.
>
> 3 It warrants that I take the measures.
>
> 4 It warranted me in taking the measures.
>
> 5 It warranted me to take the measures.

Are all the patterns grammatical? I have doubts about 3.

**I feel the urge to defend the constructions submitted by me as they were given the cold shoulder.**

> 1 Would I, for example, think that the situation **warranted my
> taking** revenge? *Stanley Tweyman · 1995*
>
> 2 I rang Sir Max Bingham to ask him if there were any members of the
> 1986–89 parliament , who are currently ministers , who had been
> involved in any improper conduct that **warranted me taking action** —
> he said there were not. *Jamie Walker · 1995*
>
> 3 missing
>
> 4 I thought then that he should have been committed to the Asylum
> instead of the Penitentiary , but I did not think **it warranted me in
> giving** him a full and free pardon . *South Carolina. General
> Assembly · 1914*
>
> 5 If my health **warranted me to hold** a position I would not ask
> anything from the Government. *United States. War Department · 1972*

Comment: None is _ungrammatical_, but I'm not sure how idiomatic  3-5 are. It's better to say "I am warranted (justified) in taking the measures" (or "The measures are warranted").

Comment: I think these are all very awkward/stilted. None of these are natural/idiomatic in modern English.  Try this instead: "I was warranted in taking these measures", or "These measures were warranted".

Comment: Another option would be "It warranted my taking the measures." All these are fairly formal, so you may as well use the formal "my" rather than "me". Whether you use present or past tense will depend on whether you're talking about the past or present!

Comment: I feel like the most natural, idiomatic phrasing is that "It warranted taking the measures", or "It warranted measures", not "It warranted *me*".

Comment: FYI, we normally "take measures". We do not "take **the** measures" unless it's already clear from the context which measures were taken, in which case, it's more natural to say, "take **these/those** measures".